# jquery-ui : drag and drop doesn't allow me to drag more than one instance of element

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am developing a small web application that uses jquery's drag and drop.
Problem is as following:

I've got a toolbox, where users can see a list of items. I'd like to give them the ability to drag as many items from that toolbox to the main canvas (or page).

Currently, after the first element is dragged, all of a sudden the css class that the toolbox was previously given (ui-draggable) disappears, and the element can no longer be dragged.

If you look at this code example (somebody else provided it, not me), you'll see the same issue. 
http://examples.placona.co.uk/drag_drop

Once you drag one of the items from the left, you can no longer drag any more of them (let alone drop them)

Why does this  happen? Is there any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6922

You will have to load a previous version of jQuery until the fix arrives. If you change the jQuery version to 1.4.4, that page will work(line 25).

```
google.load("jquery", "1.4.4");
```

Comment: You're a life saver. I spent more than an hour on that. You saved me many more, thanks :)